# How to make user but without access to public_html

Tags: linux, chroot

How to make an user for linux, who can't access public_html folder?

**UPDATE:**
Indeed I want to use `http://example.com/~user/` but user doesn't has any permission on other rootdir.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A user can access any directory they create, so unless you're going to give the user a home directory without write access, they will be able to create a `public_html` directory and access it.

If you are using the `userdir` apache module, you can use a custom name or set up the Apache configuration to have a `Require all denied` directive for locations in that user's home.

By default, normal users don't have write access to `/var/www/html`, so with the `userdir` mod, the only site a user can modify is their own.